# Javascript Millionaire Calculator Loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, calculator

I'm coding a calculator in Javascript that works out how long it will take someone to become a millionaire by calculating the following factors: Monthly Deposit and Return on Investment. To figure this out I need an Amortization schedule so that the interest is added onto the savings each month.
See code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function computeMillion(){
    var deposit = document.getElementById('deposit').value;
    var interest = document.getElementById('return').value;
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;

    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            interestPayment = deposit * interest;
            principalPayment = deposit - interestPayment;
            principal -= principalPayment;
        }
    var months = amount / principal;
    document.getElementById('months').innerHTML = "Months to Millionaire ="+months;     

}
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>Amount Desired: £<input id="amount" type="number" value="1000000" onChange="computeMillion()"></p>
<p>Monthly Deposit: £<input id="deposit" type="number" onChange="computeMillion()"></p>
<p>Return on Investment: <input id="interest" type="number" onChange="computeMillion()">%</p>

<h2 id="months"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

So if a deposit of £50 was made initially, after that first month the savings should be £52.50 because of the interest of 5% that the user would input, the following month another £50 would be saved meaning that there is £102.50 in the account and then interest is added onto that which woudl equal £107.62 and so on.

Can anyone see the code that isn't working? I can enter the amounts required but I get no results show up at all.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 5; bank++)` ??? why `bank++` ? not `i++` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As I found...*

Why `bank++` when you using `i`?

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; bank++)
```

**Try :**

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

or something like..

**HTML :**

```
<p>Amount Desired: £<input id="amount" type="number" value="1000000" onkeyup="computeMillion()"></p>
<p>Monthly Deposit: £<input id="deposit" type="number" onkeyup="computeMillion()"></p>
<p>Return on Investment:<input id="interest" type="number" onkeyup="computeMillion()">%</p>
<h2 id="months"></h2>
```

**JS :**

```
function computeMillion() {
    var deposit = document.getElementById('deposit').value || 0;
    var interest = document.getElementById('interest').value || 0;
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value || 0;
    var principal;
    // var principal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        interestPayment = deposit * interest;
        principalPayment = deposit - interestPayment;
        principal = principalPayment;
        // principal -= principalPayment;
    }
    var months = amount / principal;
    document.getElementById('months').innerHTML = "Months to Millionaire =" + months;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xkr5cky4/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have ammended code which has had no effect.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! At least it shows results now.. I think i may have my math wrong to calculate it. This is how i'd like it to work, forgetting the styling http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/saving/article-1633423/Millionaire-calculator-How-long-make-1m-How-regular-savings-make-rich.html

Answer (score 1):

for(i = 0; i < 5; bank++)

change to

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the variable principle needs to be defined outside of the for statement for results to show up.

Also I'd recommend a loop rather than a for condition which waits until your value is equal to or greater than 1 mill then display the months.